# Making a foreign key reference only a subset of rows in the referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using MS SQL SERVER 2019.

In my database I have a table `Events` which stores events offered by a club

```
Events (Theme, Event_Date, Place, Event_Hour, Type)
```

Then I also have a table `Reservations` which stores reservations for those events:

```
Reservations (Id, Event_Theme)       FK(Event_Theme) --> PK(Events.Theme)
```

My goal is to allow insertion of new rows in `Reservations` only if `Event_Theme` for that row is a theme of a future event (i.e one with `Event_Date` > CURRENT DATE): obviously reservations are not allowed for past events.

My attempt was the creation, inside `Reservations` table's creation, of the following check constraint:

```
  CONSTRAINT CHK_Reservations_Event_Theme   CHECK (Event_Theme IN (SELECT STRING_AGG(E.Theme, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY E.Theme ASC)
                                                                   FROM Events E
                                                                   WHERE E.Event_Date>=(CAST( GETDATE() AS Date))))
```

But I then remembered that **subqueries aren't supported for check constraints**

What is an alternative way to implement the same logic?

Comment: use simple triggers

Comment: @nbk    Could you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the example event number 2 is outdated, so a new row is not inserted.

Event number 1 can be inserted.

you can add more and more conditions to the `WHERE` for example if only 100 reservations can be made

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Events (Theme int , Event_Date date, Place varchar(4), Event_Hour int, Type int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Events VALUES(1, DATEADD(month, 1, getdate()), 'A',1,1),
> (2, DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()), 'B',2,2)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE Reservations (Id int, Event_Theme int)
> ```

> ```
>  CREATE TRIGGER tr_Reservations ON Reservations
> INSTEAD OF INSERT 
> AS
> BEGIN 
>
> INSERT INTO [Reservations](
>   [Id],
>   [Event_Theme])
> SELECT  Id,[Event_Theme]  
> FROM INSERTED
> WHERE Event_Theme IN (SELECT STRING_AGG(E.Theme, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY E.Theme ASC)
>                                                                    FROM [Events] E
>                                                                    WHERE E.Event_Date>=(CAST( GETDATE() AS Date)));
> PRINT 'success.';
>
>   END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Reservations VALUES (1,1),(2,2)
> ```

success.
3 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Reservations
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Event_Theme
> -: | ----------:
>  1 |           1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=147b7c1bf53f14ed69c8ba19431121f7)*

Answer (score 0):

I found also a way without using a trigger.

I created the following stored function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION usf_CHECK_THEME(@EventTheme VARCHAR(45))
RETURNS VARCHAR(45)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Theme VARCHAR(45);
    SET @Theme =NULL;
    SET @Theme = (SELECT E.Theme
                 FROM  Events E
                 WHERE E.Theme=@EventTheme  AND E.Event_Date>(CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)));
RETURN @Theme;
END;
```

Theme is PK In table `Events`.

And then in the check constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT CHK_Reservations_Event_Theme CHECK (usf_CHECK_THEME(Event_Theme) IS NOT NULL)
```